# Conferences and training for architects, best practices,

Tags: architecture

It's getting close to the time when I need to submit training and travel requests. I'm looking for conferences and classes in the coming 12 months that are geared toward improving coding and software development, best practices, system architecture, etc. They need to be in the US or Canada since I'll never get approval for anything else.

Here are a few that I've found, but I'm looking for other suggestions. Also feedback on any of these would be appreciated too:
[Software Process Symposium](http://www.spsymposium.com/agenda.html)
[Software Development Best Practices](http://sdbestpractices.com/index.php?option=com_frontpage&Itemid=1)
 [Better Software Conference](http://www.sqe.com/bettersoftwareconf/)
[IASA Connections](http://www.iasaconnections.com/shows/iasa2008fall/default.asp?s=119)

The IASA event looks like the closest match for me but doesn't give me enough lead time to request & schedule it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Microsoft technologies, the [patterns & practices Summit](http://www.pnpsummit.com/) is a good event -- if you are not working pretty much  100% in the Microsoft .NET space, though, it would be of less use.

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend the Nothin’ but .NET Developer Boot Camp 
more information http://www.jpboodhoo.com/training.oo

Answer (score 1):

Carnegie Mellon University's Software Engineering Institute--in Pittsburgh, PA--has certification programs and trainings on Software Architecture:

- http://www.sei.cmu.edu/architecture/certificate_program.html

Answer (score 0):

[InfoQ](http://infoq.com/)'s conferences seem to be valuable. Some parts of their materials is available online.

Answer (score 0):

I also found this, but there is not a class currently scheduled:
[Agile Boot Camp for .NET Journeyman to Master Series](http://www.agileuniversity.org/course_details.jsp?courseid=157)

Here is one that is scheduled that looks like it might actually be the same thing:
[Headspring Agile Boot Camp](http://www.headspringsystems.com/services/training/)

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't successful in getting budget, maybe you could consider attending local user groups such as OWASP. I participate in [OWASP Hartford](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Hartford).

Answer (score 0):

You can do IASA online training and certification and similarly from another source for .NET http://www.soaschool.com/certifications/net